# How to use the Java API in Kotlin to send a POST request with JSON data to Elasticsearch 8.x?

Tags: java, json, kotlin, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use the Java API in Kotlin to send a POST request with JSON data to Elasticsearch 8.x. I've set up my Elasticsearch client as follows:

```
val restClient = RestClient.builder(
    HttpHost("localhost", 9200)
).build()

// Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
val transport: ElasticsearchTransport = RestClientTransport(
    restClient, JacksonJsonpMapper()
)

// And create the API client
val client = ElasticsearchClient(transport)
```

I would like to send a whole JSON document to Elasticsearch using the POST request, but I'm not sure how to do it. I've seen examples using the IndexRequest class because as far as I've read is the right path for 8.x version that should use java api

Could someone provide an example of how to send a POST request with JSON data to Elasticsearch using the Java API? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved: This problem is caused by android
On Android making network calls on the main thread that handles the UI is forbidden as it can make the application unresponsive

You should do these calls from another thread, or use the async version RestClient.performRequestAsync().

link for the async version: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/8.7/java-rest-low-usage-requests.html

Answer (score 0):

from the docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/indexing.html

you have examples of how to index single docs using the fluent DSL, classic builders, async client, and - as you requested - using raw JSON data

Comment: I triend what you suggested converting the java code in kotlin. but the last instruction generate a java runtime error val input: Reader = StringReader(
                "[...]"
                    .replace('\'', '"')
            )
            val request = IndexRequest.of(
                Function { i: IndexRequest.Builder<JsonData?> ->
                    i
                        .index("logsxe")
                        .withJson(input)
                }
            )
            val response: IndexResponse = client.index(request)

Comment: I even tried to use the client.search from the same official source used to connect to elasticsearch server (here is the link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/connecting.html)